# How to associate a nomad policy to workload by wildcard

Tags: acl, policy, nomad

With Hashicorp's Nomad, I've followed the steps outlined in the [Workload associated ACL policies](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/variables/variables-tasks#workload-associated-acl-policies) section of the [Accessing variables from tasks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/variables/variables-tasks) tutorial and I have it working.

Here is an example of the policy file named `sensitive.policy.hcl`:

```json
namespace "sensitive" {
  variables {
    path "*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }

    path "azure/*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected when applying it to a real job:

```
$ nomad namespace apply -description "Namespace for sensitive variables" sensitive
$ nomad var put -namespace sensitive @../path/to/sensitive.nv.hcl
$ nomad acl policy apply -description "Sensitive policy" -namespace default -job ARealJobThatExists sensitive /path/to/sensitive.policy.hcl
```

and then use it in a template:

```json
job "ARealJobThatExists" {
  ...
  group "example" {
    ...
    task "example" {
      ...
      # Template to load sensitive properties into ENV VARs
      template {
        change_mode          = "restart"
        error_on_missing_key = true
        destination          = "${NOMAD_SECRETS_DIR}/.azure"
        data                 = <<EOT
{{- with nomadVar "azure/properties@system" -}}
PROP1 = {{ .prop1 }}
PROP2 = {{ .prop2 }}
{{- end -}}
EOT
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like to associate the same policy to *multiple workloads* (jobs) that don't yet exist. In other words, I want to proactively associate the policy to a wildcard of jobs so that the new jobs (created by coworkers) will automatically have read access to existing secrets. The coworkers can list the secrets/variables but not read them.

I tried the following, without success:

```
$ nomad acl policy apply -description "Proactive sensitive policy" -namespace default -job "*" sensitive /path/to/sensitive.policy.hcl
```

Inspecting the policy returns the following:

```
$ nomad acl policy info sensitive
Name        = sensitive
Description = Proactive sensitive policy
CreateIndex = 12070
ModifyIndex = 12070

Associated Workload
Namespace = default
JobID     = *
Group     = <none>
Task      = <none>
```

Is there a way to achieve this or should I put in a feature request?

Comment: I see a similar question was asked and answered on the Nomad community forum, but it doesn't provide a solution: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/nomad-vars-and-usage-and-audit/49242